# What does it mean "specialized populations of neurons"?

Tags: neuroanatomy

I'm reading now the Campbell biology book (10th), and on page 1063 is written:

> In all but the simplest animals, **specialized populations of
>   neurons** handle each stage of information processing.

What does it mean "specialized populations of neurons"? I always knew that there is a population in biological hierarchy of creatures rather than the cells which assemble the creatures.

Comment: As in the occipital lobe handling vision processing, the prefrontal lobe intiating motor activities, etc...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about English language usage, not biological terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a specialized *group* of neurons. You can call a group of cells a population of cells. They are specialized because those particular neurons carry out a specific function.